# "OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected" on import

Tags: google-colaboratory

After installing a package

> `!pip install umap-learn`

I want to import it

> `import umap`

but can't get past the error

> OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: '{path_to_notebook}'

Other answers regarding this error suggest

- restarting runtime
- umounting and remounting GDrive.

I tried both solutions multiple times, on different days, and am not getting results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally solved the problem was installing `umap` *before* mounting GDrive.